# how to add dependency in npm package to download another npm package?

Tags: angular, npm, build-dependencies

I am building an angular app's npm package which will have a dependency on another package which is already available on npm. My dependency object will look somehow like this, 
`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "ars-components": "file:dist/ars-components",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "ssi-package2": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    **"service1": "npm i ssi-service1"**
  },`

I want it to install *service1* on installation using this command **npm i ssi-service1**. I have published my package but on installation time it gives an error like this;

> npm ERR! Invalid tag name "npm i ssi-service1": Tags may not have any
>   characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

Any help to achieve this goal will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need to `npm i` within your package.json

Only add the npm package with your version (like @angular) to the file:

```
“ssi-service1” : “1.0.0”
```

After that, run `npm i` in the root of your package.json to pull the (missing) packages.

Or just run: `npm i —save ssi-service1` from the command line and it will be added to.

Comment: thanks for your response. But now it has started giving this error on installation, "npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\ssi-package2\dist\ars-components" as it does not contain a package.json file."

Comment: so you don’t have a package.json file?

Comment: "ssi-package2" isn't installed yet. So, it will not have any folder or package.json file before installation. This whole path i.e ""node_modules\ssi-package2\dist\ars-components"" don't exist on my system.